# sqlite selected data not showing to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am calling the data from listItems.push(res.rows.item(i).name); to a list  by ng-repeat. so that i got a list of names that are present in SQLite.

This is my controllers.js

```
$scope.createList = function () {

    var value1 = document.getElementById("List").value;
    alert(value1);
    var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "Bd_DB.db" });

    var query = "INSERT INTO List (name) VALUES (?)";

    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [value1]).then(function (res) {

        console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId);
    }, function (err) {
        alert(err);
        console.error(err);
    });

    $scope.getAllLists();

};

$scope.getAllLists = function () {

    var listItems= [];
    var query = "SELECT * FROM List";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute($cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "Bd_DB.db" }), query).then(function (res) {

        if (res.rows.item(0).name !="") {

            for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {

              listItems.push(res.rows.item(i).name);



            }
        }

    });

}
```

I have tried ,  and  but it is not showing any kind of list. i don't know, what i m doing wrong. please tell me the right code. Thanks
This is my Html:

```
 <div class="bar bar-header">
  <button class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear button-dark"            ng-click="closeModal()" ></button>
  <h1 class="title">Your List</h1>
  <button class="button" ng-click="createListPopup()"> Create List</button>
</div>
```

My ToDo List

```
<ion-content>


      <div ng-repeat= "name in listItems">

    {{item.name}}

  </div>


</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2):

sqlite transaction is synchronous, so in the create list, you have to call the getList in the success callback of the execute:
like:
 $scope.createList = function () {

```
var value1 = document.getElementById("List").value;
alert(value1);
var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "Bd_DB.db" });

var query = "INSERT INTO List (name) VALUES (?)";

$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [value1]).then(function (res) {

    console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId);
     $scope.getAllLists();

}, function (err) {
    alert(err);
    console.error(err);
});
```

};

Also, in the getAllLists, the function will end regardless of the status of the .execute, so you have to bind to a variable which be set inside the success callback.

```
$scope.listItems= [];
```

$scope.getAllLists = function () {

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM List";
$cordovaSQLite.execute($cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "Bd_DB.db" }), query).then(function (res) {
    $scope.listItems= [];
    if (res.rows.item(0).name !="") {

        for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {

          listItems.push(res.rows.item(i).name);

        }
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

Finally, you have to made $scope.$apply() to reflect the result to the view.

Comment: Wow, this works! I just add the "$scope.$apply();" line, which really confuses me, seems no code "outside angularjs framework" here, so why should $apply be used?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `var listItems= []` to a scope variable

```
$scope.listItems = [];
....
$scope.listItems.push({name:'item 1'})
```

and then in your view:

```
<ion-content>
  <div ng-repeat= "item in listItems">
      {{item.name}}
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: still not getting anything. In console Elements it is showing that ng-repeat is commented nothing else.

Comment: Hey Salman, did you manage to solve this issue, somehow? I am also facing the same issue. ng-repeat is commented automatically.

Comment: hey @vkm , sorry for replying late. I solved that issue by putting listItems in a $scope and then call that $scope in my view.